# What's the difference between acquire(number) and acquire() in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I had to make 2 threads that execute alternately and also one of them has to execute N times more than the other.

```
public void init(int count) {
     semaphore1 = new Semaphore(1);
     semaphore2 = new Semaphore(0);
     num=count;
}

class F1Thread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        semaphore1.acquire();
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        f1();
        semaphore2.release();
    }

class F2Thread extends Thread {

    public void run()  {
       semaphore2.acquire();
       f2();
       semaphore1.release();
    }
```

This is my solution but before that i tried acquiring all the permits instead of 1 and doing a loop

```
public void init(int count) {
     semaphore1 = new Semaphore(count);
     semaphore2 = new Semaphore(0);
     num=count;
}

class F1Thread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        semaphore1.acquire(count);
        f1();
        semaphore2.release();
    }

class F2Thread extends Thread {

    public void run()  {
       semaphore2.acquire();
       f2();
       semaphore1.release(count);
    }
```

My point is

```
 for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
 semaphore.acquire();
```

and

```
semaphore.acquire(number);
```

shouldn't perform the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the semaphore has 5 permits,

- 10 times `acquire()` would acquire 5 and block.
- `acquire(10)` would immediately block, till 10 permits are released.

However I did not find this behaviour in the javadocs, nor after eyeing the sources.

It seems that a greedy `acquire(number)` could mean other threads with a lesser number always pass first.

Unfortunately I did not find a specification.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was asking